# Neo4j Cypher Query: Finding all nodes, that are connected to a node, that has more than 3 other relationships

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a problem with my Cypher query. I have some nodes called `:SENTENCE` and some other called `:WORD`. `:SENTENCE` nodes have relationships `:CONTAINS` to `:WORD` nodes.

I want to find `:SENTENCE` nodes, that are connected to `:WORD` nodes, that are used from more than 3 other `:SENTENCE` nodes. All `:WORD` nodes have to comply this criterion.

I tried something like this:

```
MATCH p=(s1:SENTENCE)-[:CONTAINS]-(w:WORD)-[:CONTAINS]-(s2:SENTENCE)
WITH s1,w, COUNT(s2) as num 
WHERE num > 3  
RETURN s1
LIMIT 25
```

But the result contains `:SENTENCE` nodes, where one and not all `:WORD` nodes have a degree of minimum 3.

Some other try:

```
MATCH p=(s1:SENTENCE)-[:CONTAINS]-(w:WORD)-[:CONTAINS]-(s2:SENTENCE)
WHERE SIZE((:SENTENCE)-[:CONTAINS]-(w:WORD)) > 3 
RETURN s1
LIMIT 25
```

But this does not hold for any `:WORD` nodes that is contained in an Sentence. It only holds for 1.

So my question is: How can I make a query that the condition hold for all nodes and not only for one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of requirement usually requires collecting nodes and using the `all()` function to ensure some predicate holds true for all elements of the collection:

```
MATCH (s1:SENTENCE)-[:CONTAINS]-(w:WORD)
WITH s1, collect(w) as words
WHERE all(word in words WHERE size((word)-[:CONTAINS]-()) > 3)
RETURN s1
LIMIT 25
```